# The Banach spaces $(\mathbb{R^2}, \Vert\cdot\Vert_1)$ and $(\mathbb{R^2}, \Vert\cdot\Vert_{\infty})$ are linearly isometric.(T/F)

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, normed-spaces, isometry

The Banach spaces $(\mathbb{R^2}, \Vert\cdot\Vert_1)$ and $(\mathbb{R^2}, \Vert\cdot\Vert_{\infty})$ are linearly isometric.(T/F)

i.e $\Vert Tx\Vert_{\infty}=\Vert  x\Vert_{1}$ but after that I can't think , please help.

Comment: The isometric isomorphism is the $45^0$ rotation plus a rescaling matrix in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: Hint: sketch the unit balls of both norms.

Comment: Please make it simple

Answer (score 2):

**The statement is true.**

Let $\ell^1(2) = (\mathbb{R}^2,\|\cdot\|_1)$ and $\ell^\infty(2)=(\mathbb{R}^2,\|\cdot\|_\infty).$

Define $T:\ell^\infty(2) \to \ell^1(2)$ by 
$$T \begin{pmatrix}
x \\
y
\end{pmatrix} = \frac{1}{2} \begin{pmatrix}
x-y\\
x+y
\end{pmatrix}.$$
We claim that $T$ is an onto linear isometry. 
For any $\begin{pmatrix}
x \\
y
\end{pmatrix} \in \ell^\infty(2),$ we have 
$$\left\Vert T \begin{pmatrix}
x \\
y
\end{pmatrix} \right\Vert_1 = \left\Vert\frac{1}{2} \begin{pmatrix}
x-y\\
x+y
\end{pmatrix}\right\Vert_1 = \frac{|x-y| + |x+y|}{2} = \max\{|x|,|y| \} = \left\Vert \begin{pmatrix}
x \\
y
\end{pmatrix} \right\Vert_\infty$$
where the second last identity is standard in any real analysis text.
Therefore, $T$ is an isometry.

Clearly $T$ is linear. 
We claim that $S:\ell^1(2)\to\ell^\infty(2)$ given by 
$$S\begin{pmatrix}
x \\
y
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
x+y\\
-x+y
\end{pmatrix}$$ is the inverse of $T.$
Indeed, 
$$(S \circ T)\begin{pmatrix}
x \\
y
\end{pmatrix} = S \left[ \frac{1}{2} \begin{pmatrix}
x-y\\
x+y
\end{pmatrix} \right] = \frac{1}{2} \begin{pmatrix}
2x\\
2y
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
x\\
y
\end{pmatrix}, $$
$$(T \circ S) \begin{pmatrix}
x\\
y
\end{pmatrix} = T \left[ \begin{pmatrix}
x+y\\
-x+y
\end{pmatrix} \right] = \frac{1}{2} \begin{pmatrix}
2x\\
2y
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
x\\
y
\end{pmatrix}.$$
Therefore, $T$ is a bijection. 
Hence, $\ell^\infty(2) \cong \ell^1(2).$

Comment: No need to check that $T$ is a bijection. Linear isometries between finite-dimensional spaces of equal dimension are automatically bijective, and their inverses are also linear isometries.